# ¿Por qué mi useState no está siendo ejecutado?

Tags: reactjs, usestate

Tengo una ruta privada (aclaro que soy nuevo en esto). Lo que trato de hacer es algo simple, solo quiero devolver un componente si userDetails es verdadero, sino, pues otro componente.

```
const PrivateRoute = () => {


 const [logged, setLogged] = useState();
  

  useEffect(() => {
      alert('entra en el efect')
      const userDetails = true;

    if (userDetails) {
        alert('entra en true')
      setLogged( true );
      alert(logged)
    } else {
        alert('entra en false')
      setLogged(false);
    }
  }, []);


  return logged ? <Home /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
};
```

Sin embargo, el comportamiento cuando ejecuto este código es:

1. 'Entra en el effect'
2. 'Entra en el true'
3. undefined

Entiendo que es undefined porque el estado inicial del state es ese, porque si le pongo

```
const [logged, setLogged] = useState(false);
```

pues imprime false.

Eso quiere decir que se está saltando la línea del `setLogged` y no entiendo qué es lo que no estoy teniendo en cuenta. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No eres el primero que tiene este problema. Es un error muy fácil de cometer al empezar a programar con React. Te recomiendo que leas mi artículo [Dentro de la caja negra de “setState”](https://desarrollos-web-urquiza.medium.com/dentro-de-la-caja-negra-de-setstate-69001c7c6ea4) para que entiendas cuál es tu fallo y cómo arreglarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esta manera:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const PrivateRoute = () => {
const [logged, setLogged] = useState();
 useEffect(() => {
     const userDetails = true;
    if (userDetails) {
        setLogged(true);
    } else {
        setLogged(false);
    }
}, []);

if (!logged) {
    return (
         <Navigate to="/login" />
    )
}
return (
    <Home />
)};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

OJO te sale false xq el estado no ha cambiado no es un cambio al instante ya que tenemos que darle tiempo a react que actualice el componente, al salir del useEffect ya te tendría que llevar el valor false o true.